# Querying Intellisense information from a visual studio extension project

Tags: c#, intellisense

I am trying to develop an extension for visual studio and I need to figure out a way to query information about intellisense: such as given a variable name - what is type of this variable?

I thought maybe there is a COM object I can use to access the intellisense.. but I couldn't find information about it in the internet.

So how can I discover the type of a given variable name in a specified source file(written in C++ or C#) from a VS Extension add-in project?

Comment: This open source extension performs such an operation: https://github.com/SLaks/Ref12

Comment: I need it to work with C++ code also, is there a way to get semantic information about c++ code? (maybe through connecting to the intellisense of Visual Studio?)